# How can I use LINQ to get the instance with the highest value of a property in a child list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, max, aggregate

I have the following class structure:

```csharp
public class FirstClass
{
    public string EmployeeNo { get; set; }

    public List<SecondClass> SecondClass { get; set; }
}

public class SecondClass
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this code:

```csharp
var result = FirstClass.Where(fc => fc.SecondClass.Aggregate((item1, item2) => item1.Count > item2.Count ? item1 : item2));
```

However, it results in this compiler error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type of "SecondClass" into bool

How can I get the `FirstClass` object containing the `SecondClass` object with the highest value of the `SecondClass.Count` property?  If multiple `FirstClass` objects have the same highest value it should return the first such object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select the count of each item in SecondClass and use [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.max?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-max(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((system-int32)))) to find the maximum value. Then you select this value of each item in FirstClass and use `Max` again:

```
int highestCount = input.Select(x => x.SecondClass.Select(y => y.Count).Max()).Max();
```

If you want to find the item with the highest count, you can replace the first Select by OrderByDescending and the second Max by FirstOrDefault:

```
var itemWithHighestCount = input.OrderByDescending(x => x.SecondClass.Select(y => y.Count).Max()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/0rWARC

Comment: what if I want to Select the whole FirstClass which has the max count

Comment: You should write this in your question. You wrote that you want to find the "highest count from SecondClass", not the item of FirstClass with the highest count in second class. But if you want to do this, try replace the first select by OrderByDescending and the second Max by FirstOrDefault

Comment: There are overloads of `Max()` that take a `selector` parameter so you can have it compare arbitrary values without the use of `Select()` (e.g. `x.SecondClass.Select(y => y.Count).Max()` → `x.SecondClass.Max(y => y.Count)`).

Answer (score 0):

Getting the maximum value of `SecondClass.Count` for a given `FirstClass` instance is straightforward...

```csharp
int maxSecondClassCount = first.SecondClass.Max(second => second.Count);
```

...although note that `Max()` will `throw` an `InvalidOperationException` if `first.SecondClass` is empty.  You can then use...

- ...the [`MaxBy()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.maxby) of **.NET 6** to get the `FirstClass` instance with that maximum `SecondClass.Count` value...

  ```csharp
  FirstClass firstClassWithMaxSecondClassCount = firstClassCollection.MaxBy(first => first.SecondClass.Max(second => second.Count));
  ```

  The [MoreLINQ library](https://morelinq.github.io/) also provides a [`MaxBy` extension method](https://morelinq.github.io/3.3/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_MaxBy.htm).
- ...the [`Aggregate()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) of **all .NET (Framework/Core) versions** supporting LINQ to enumerate your `FirstClass` instances, keep track of the instance with the maximum value for `SecondClass.Count`, and return that `FirstClass` instance at the end...

  ```csharp
  FirstClass firstClassWithMaxSecondClassCount = firstClassCollection.Aggregate(
      (element: default(FirstClass), count: 0), // The initial value of currentMax
      (currentMax, currentElement) => {
          int currentElementMaxCount = currentElement.SecondClass.Max(second => second.Count);

          return currentElementMaxCount > currentMax.count
              ? (element: currentElement, count: currentElementMaxCount)
              : currentMax;
      },
      currentMax => currentMax.element          // The return value given the final value of currentMax
  );
  ```

  That uses a [tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) to store the maximum value of  `SecondClass.Count` alongside the containing `FirstClass` instance so that value doesn't have to be recalculated in each invocation.  Otherwise, this less complex but also less performant code could be used...

  ```csharp
  FirstClass firstClassWithMaxSecondClassCount = firstClassCollection.Aggregate(
      (maxElement, currentElement) => 
          currentElement.SecondClass.Max(second => second.Count) > maxElement.SecondClass.Max(second => second.Count)
              ? currentElement : maxElement
  );
  ```

  The advantage of using `Aggregate()` instead of sorting and taking the element at one end of the result is that `Aggregate()` only needs to store one other value — the accumulator (`currentMax`/`maxElement` above) — as it enumerates the source sequence whereas sorting will require buffering the entire sequence to that point.